# Ajax call to Python script. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

What am I doing wrong here please. I want to run an very basic python script on the server side and the get the return value to the client side (ie javascript)
My python script is:

```
// Hello.py
--------------------------
import sys

def hello(str):
    print('Hello ' + str)
    return 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello(*sys.argv[1:])
```

and my Ajax call:

```
function getAjax(url, data){
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : url,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            return response;
        }
    });
 }

 getAjax("./scripts/hello.py", 'John').done(function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

When I run `getAjax` the `console.log(response)` statement just prints the text (ie code) in my Python script. What is the step I am missing here please?

Comment: So you just have a file sitting in a directory and you're expecting it to execute based off an AJAX call? That's not how it works. You need to have that python script running and callable by a url. Look into Flask or Django.

Comment: This python script is not running on a server...

Answer (score 2):

You need a server for link an http request from your browser on a specific port (default 80) of your network target and get the reponse of a specific script, the most simple usage for local tests like this in python is to use something like simplehttpserver: https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html